# XML Android actionbar Item dropdown options

Tags: java, android, xml, menu, android-actionbar

I have a item in my actionbar, when i click on it I want to have 2 options to chose from.
This is what i have now:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/createnew"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="CREATE"/>
</menu>
```

I want something like this:

[image: 1]

(sorry can't post images yet, not enough rep)
I hope someone is able to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another item, like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/createnew"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="CREATE"/>
<item
        android:id="@+id/other_tiem"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="OTHER"/>
</menu>
```

PS: if you don't want your items to appear in the actionbar when there is room, change `yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"` into `yourapp:showAsAction="never"` and will look like the one in your image.

For creating groups use something like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

   <group 
      android:id="@+id/create" 
      android:orderInCategory="1"
      yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom">

      <item android:id="@+id/option_one"
          android:title="@string/option_one" />
      <item android:id="@+id/option_two"
          android:title="@string/option_two" />
  </group>

  <item
      android:id="@+id/other_item"
      android:orderInCategory="2"
      yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
      android:title="OTHER"/>
</menu>
```

To replicated the design you want:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

   <group 
      android:id="@+id/create" 
      android:orderInCategory="1"
      yourapp:showAsAction="always"
      android:icon="@drawable/group_icon">

      <item android:id="@+id/option_one"
          android:title="@string/option_one" />

      <item android:id="@+id/option_two"
          android:title="@string/option_two" />

  </group>

</menu>
```

I think I didn't understood correctly what you want. This should be more like what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/create"
          android:icon="@drawable/create_icon"
          android:title="@string/create_title"
           yourapp:showAsAction="always" >

        <!-- "create" submenu -->
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/option_one"
                  android:title="@string/option_one" />
            <item android:id="@+id/option_two"
                  android:title="@string/option_two" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: i tried it but then i get it next to CREATE. What i want it is: when i click on CREATE i want two options, i want to make it a dropdown.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include groups of items.

Comment: I did try that but instead of the text CREATE i get the 3 dots. i want to replace the 3 dots with text or another icon.
 This is the screeenshot what i get now:
http://prntscr.com/3piyk4

Comment: I have updated my answer. I think I didn't understood correctly what you neede. I hope the last change is what you want.
Best regards.